# Same Name Element with Different Values - XML / XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a sample XML below with same name elements but with different values. I am creating a reporting using XSLT and need to pull the data from XML based on the value.

XSLT :

Client Gender : ALL
Choice of Accommodation : Basic
Veterans Only : All
Display Client Characteristics : Yes

XML :

```
<placement:WaitlistFilter>
    <placement:Name>Client Gender</placement:Name>
    <placement:Value>All</placement:Value>
  </placement:WaitlistFilter>

  <placement:WaitlistFilter>
    <placement:Name>Choice of Accommodation</placement:Name>
    <placement:Value>Basic</placement:Value>
  </placement:WaitlistFilter>

  <placement:WaitlistFilter>
    <placement:Name>Application Status</placement:Name>
    <placement:Value>All</placement:Value>
  </placement:WaitlistFilter>

  <placement:WaitlistFilter>
    <placement:Name>Veterans Only</placement:Name>
    <placement:Value>All</placement:Value>
  </placement:WaitlistFilter>

  <placement:WaitlistFilter>
    <placement:Name>Display Client Characteristics</placement:Name>
    <placement:Value>Yes</placement:Value>
  </placement:WaitlistFilter>
```

As you can see above , i will have collection same element names with different values. I will have to first Match the Placement Name like Display Client Characteristics and then get the Value Yes.

How would i do that ? Basically i have get to that element and match the test then get the value.

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Ally

Comment: What is the **exact** result you are trying to produce? -- P.S. Please edit your input XML example and make it complete (i.e.well-formed).

Comment: I am trying to find Element Name where it is Veterans Only and once matched then get the Value which is ALL. Same for all other elements.

Comment: Yes, I understood *that*. What i am missing is what do you want to do with it once you get it. And your input cannot be processed because it has no root element and the `placement` prefix is not bound to a namespace - so please fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general XPath form you are looking for is:

```
placement:WaitListFilter[placement:Name = 'Veterans Only']/placement:Value
```

I'm making a bunch of assumptions here, but if you understand this XPath, you should be able to adjust it to your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks man , exactly this is what is need. I don't know why i got -1